# Have Window ignore interactivity (Ghost/Overlay window)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a window which has a FormBorderStyle of None with a picturebox docked on the form. So essentially all that is showing is a photo. I now have it set to Top Most. What I want done is if they click somewhere on the image it will ignore the click on that window and interact with the window under it. I did this thinking it would work but it doesn't. I am guessing the click isn't fast enough for the form to show, or I may have to close or minimize the form.

```
    Me.Hide()
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Me.Show()
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Win32 programming model, the type of window you're describing is called a "transparent" window.

Note that this is distinct from *opacity*, with which it often gets confused. A transparent window is see-through to events like mouse clicks, but it may still be *opaque* (i.e., not visually transparent). You can have both hit-test transparency and visual transparency, or only one, or neither.

To make a window hit-test transparent, you need to set the [`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended window style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) when you create the window.

To do that from VB.NET, override your form's [`CreateParams` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.createparams.aspx) and add the style flag, like so:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
    Get
        Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = &H20

        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

Note that when you make a window transparent, you get a fully transparent window, just like you asked. That means it will be *completely invisible* to mouse clicks, including on the non-client area. The user won't even be able to click the close box in the upper-left. The application must close the window programmatically. You need to account for this in your design.

---

Toggling the style on and off requires a bit more code. You need to P/Invoke the Win32 functions for retrieving and setting the current window styles. For example:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
' ...etc.

Public Class MyForm : Inherits Form

    ' P/Invoke stuff

    Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Integer = -20
    Private Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = &H20

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                             nIndex As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                            nIndex As Integer, _
                                            dwNewLong As IntPtr) As IntPtr                                                
    End Function

    ' Toggling function
    Public Sub ToggleClickTransparency()
        ' Get the form's current extended window styles.
        Dim exStyle As IntPtr = GetWindowLongPtr(Me.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE)

        ' Determine if the transparency flag is currently set.
        If (exStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT) = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT Then
            ' Remove the flag.
            exStyle = exStyle And (Not WS_EX_TRANSPARENT)
        Else
            ' Add the flag.
            exStyle = exStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        End If

        ' Update the window's styles.
        SetWindowLongPtr(Me.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle)
    End Sub

    ' Other code
    ' ...

End Class
```

Comment: Is there a way to trigger this after clicking a button on the same form, instead of having it on the form from the start?

Comment: @Ugleh Updated my answer. Call the `ToggleClickTransparency` function. Or use the logic to make separate setter functions if you like.